# Express.Js How to make a string parameter to a Json stringify Object?

Tags: json, api, express, get

I have problem how to make a query parameter to stringify json object can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you save the object as is in your database and pull it using the primary key attached to the object? That should make for a cleaner API path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are a library which perfect fits what are you've looking for

[qs library](https://github.com/ljharb/qs)

It can handle objects to querystring and querystring to objects